# Modifying code that has already been pushed in Git

Tags: git

I am working on user story say US 2001:Test user story and I made two push to remote server. Code was reviewed and merged in the branch. In this I did following

```
1.First Push

   git commit -m "US 2001:Test user story"
   git pull --rebase origin master 
   git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master

2. Second push
   git commit --amend
   git pull --rebase origin master 
   git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

After review reviewer merged that code to branch. Now I identified further changes in that user story.  I am confused how to commit and push the code. Now I cannot do `git commit --amend` as git log is showing commit for others on head.

Do I need make fresh commit and push the code as different change set id? I am new to Git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Consider everything that was pushed as "final".**

Yes, in order to preserve the history, you will need to base your changes on the commit that someone else already pushed. This way, once they pull, they will get your changes on top of what they already have and everyone has the same version.

> Technically, you could also go back to your first commit, add your changes using `amend`, rebase the changes from the other person on top of that, and force-push it to the upstream. This is a horrible idea because it will break the history and cause all kinds of problems for other users.

Comment: one more clarification I need from you ...Please confirm my first two push mentioned in question will have same change set id as i did git commit and git commit --amend is it ?

Comment: @Chris_vr The original commit  will have a different SHA1 hash than the new commit generated by `git commit --amend`.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need make fresh commit and push the code as different change set id ?

Yes. Using `--amend` rewrites the branch history. You should only use `--amend` for a commit that has not been pushed to any remote repo.

I personally prefer creating a new branch whenever I'm going to work on a feature so I can keep all my related commits together. I recommend you do the same:

- work on a separate branch,
- rebase regularly with master -- keeping your changes on top of master's head
- carry out the code-review in the new branch
- only merge your changes to master once they are ready and reviewed. Better still ask your reviewer to merge for you.